# Each tab in UITabController has many view controllers

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I want to design an app with UI like this: 
[image]

At bottom, I know it is UITabbarController. In each tab, it has many view controllers like BEAT, TOP, FUN... Each tab has different view controllers. 
When scroll horizontal, can change from BEAT to TOP to FUN... 
How can I design like that? What view controller should I use? It seems like UIPageController in UITabController, but with UIPageController, I don't know how to replace dots at bottom (.) by BEAT, TOP, FUN... at top.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution is to add UISwipeGesture(Left/Right) on view and upon swipe action you can push or pop view controllers.

In ViewController.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UISwipeGestureRecognizer * leftSwipe;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UISwipeGestureRecognizer * rightSwipe;
```

In ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupSwipeGestures];
}

-(void)setupSwipeGestures
{
    _leftSwipe=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(next)];
    [_leftSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];

    _rightSwipe =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(previous)];
    [_rightSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_leftSwipe];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_rightSwipe];    
}

- (void) previous
{
    // perform pop to get previous viewController
    // i.e [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void) next
{
    // perform push to get next viewController
    // i.e     [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

If you want to use above code in every Controller, then you may define your own viewController and paste above code in it, after that inherit all of your viewControllers where you need above functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) library in each tab of your tab controller. Awesome library, even gives you the swiping feature similar to android which can enable you to swipe through individual page sections as well as keeping tab property.

Comment: Good library. Thank you.